# Dynamic Float top positions

Tags: css, css-float

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any ideas on how I could implement a grid-view in CSS? - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379994/any-ideas-on-how-i-could-implement-a-grid-view-in-css-css)

I have an example of a dynamic number of divs all floating left:

[alt text http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7717/qaatest1.jpg](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7717/qaatest1.jpg)

...but would like the new row to be tucked up under the previous as in my example desired output:

[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1527/qaatest2.jpg](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1527/qaatest2.jpg)

I know using columns might be the best way to go but am having trouble with exactly how to go about that.  A CSS solution would be great.

I do know how many boxes there will be when i start out. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This jQuery plugin might be of help:
http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

**Edit:** I don't think a pure CSS solution is sufficient. You may know the number of columns, but you won't know the size of columns without javascript trickery. I recommend the above plugin.

Comment: Awesome! Fantastic plugin that did exactly what I needed. Many thanks.