# Any ideas on how I could implement a grid-view in CSS? - CSS

Tags: html, css, gridview, datagrid

**Here is an example grid-view:**

[image]

**Also another example from TED.com**

[image]

---

**Any ideas on how I could go on about implementing a dynamic grid like this in CSS?**

I guess it might have something to do with dividing the box in units styled with float:left, and each unit would have a border if on a boxes border.

Help would be very appreciated =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've achieved a similar grid in the past with David Desandro's awesome [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/). As that page illustrates, CSS floats aren't so great for grid layouts, and setting up "units" like you describe could be a massive headache, depending on the complexity of the grid and range of cell sizes.

Comment: pretty neat!! Thank you so much! =)

I guess there non-javascript users are below 1% so I could just use a different layout for non-javascript users. =)

I'll see if this solves the puzzle =P