# CSS Layout full of random sized divs

Tags: css, css-float

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any ideas on how I could implement a grid-view in CSS? - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379994/any-ideas-on-how-i-could-implement-a-grid-view-in-css-css)

I'm trying to create a layout that is backward from what I usually do. I have hundreds of randomly sized divs that I want to fill in as much of the page as possible. As a quick hack, it might look something like this:

```
|--------||-------------------||----||-----------|
|        ||        2          ||  3 ||     4     |
|   1    ||-------------------||    ||-----------|
|        ||-----------------|  |----|
|        ||                 ||---------|
|--------||        5        ||         |
|--------||                 ||    6    |
|    7   ||-----------------||         |
|        |                   |---------|
|--------|
```

I've been playing with float lefts, but they don't move upward to fill the gaps. How can this be done?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Which gaps are you talking about, your question is not that clear.

Comment: sorry, see how box 5 is shifted upward? When I use only "float:left", the top of 5 and 6 would be aligned with 7. I'm trying to figure out how to make them move upward as well as left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of question was asked yesterday too. The solution was to use a JQuery plugin: [Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/).

[Any ideas on how I could implement a grid-view in CSS? - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379994/any-ideas-on-how-i-could-implement-a-grid-view-in-css-css)

Comment: Found a version for mootools here: http://mootools.net/forge/p/moomasonry

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) or:

You will have to create a ***column/grid-based*** system. For example, div 1 and 7 go in their own parent div, div 2 and 5 go in their own parent div,  3 and 6 go in their own parent and so on.

You may be interested in using some of the famous grid systems:

- [45+ CSS Grid Systems](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/06/45-css-grid-systems-layout-generators-and-tutorials-that-every-designer-should-know.html)
- [4 CSS Grid Systems and Why](http://scarletbits.com/2009/4-css-grid-systems-and-why/)

You can also create the via:

- [Grid System Generator](http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/)